# Получение имени каждой inline кнопки Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram 3 Python.
Есть текстовый файлик, где в каждой строке написано имя. Все строки оттуда парсятся и на каждую строку создаются такие кнопки:

[image]

Кнопки естественно создаются динамически по каждой строке в файле

```
    with open('settings.txt', 'r') as file:
        # Читаем все строки из файла и удаляем лишние пробельные символы
        lines = [line.strip() for line in file]


    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    for line in lines:
        builder.button(
            text=f"{line}", callback_data=f"lookup_delete_service"
        )
    builder.adjust(1)
    await message.answer(" Список отслеживаемых служб:", reply_markup=builder.as_markup())
```

Так вот мне нужно при нажатии получать имя кнопки, то есть "test1", "test2" и т.д

Видел решение, где на каждую кнопку пишется свой хендлер, но я никогда не знаю точное количество кнопок.

Comment: Можно в callback_data засунуть имя кнопки, только главное чтобы callback был не больше 50 символов, а то будет ошибка